# Jquery promises whit objects

Tags: jquery, web

```
function uploadfiles(inputcontrol){ 
   //here the function takes all the files of an input files
   //for each inputcontrol.files[i]
   //createObject(inputcontrol.files[i]);
}

function createObject(files){ 
  //this function creates an object with each one of them the files 
  //are processed and loaded in a web service whit AJAX
}

when(uploadfiles()).then(alert('All files uploaded'));
```

When I run this script, the alert is displayed immediately and it does not wait for the files to be uploaded correctly. How should I run the $ .when?

Comment: Are you passing the promises/deferreds back up through `createObject` and `uploadfiles` to your `when` call? See [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#entry-examples) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your `clupload` class so it can read the file using the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, because we can now chain the process of reading the file and then upload it.

I also changed the `getBase64` function so it returns the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, this way we can use the `done` and `fail` methods later.

Here is the code:

```
class clupload {
  constructor(file, Ticket) {
    this.f = file;
    this.t = Ticket;
  }

  readFile () {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      dfd.resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.f);
    return dfd.promise();
  }

  procesar() {
    var tt = this.t;
    var nombre = this.f.name;
    var user = $('#loginUsrApp').val();
    return this.readFile().then(function (salida) {
      return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/SubirArchivo",
        data: "{T:'" + tt + "',b64:'" + salida + "',N:'" + nombre + "',U:'" + user + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
      })
    });
  }
}

function getBase64(f, T) {
  var files = document.querySelector(f).files;
  var uploads = files.map(function (file) {
    var upload = new clupload(file, T);
    return upload.procesar();
  });
  return $.when.apply($, uploads);
}
```

Now you only have to call it like this:

```
getBase64('#upload1', r.d).done(function() {
  alert('Guardado');
}).fail(function () {
  alert('Error');
});
```

Comment: I tried this
'$.when(getBase64('#upload1', r.d)).then(function () { alert('cargado'); location.reload(); });', 
but it does the same. It does not wait for the file to load, it shows the message immediately.
should I include the WHEN method within the class of the object?

Comment: `getBase64('#upload1', r.d)` should return a Deferred or Promise or Thenable object. If it's returning a list you should call it like this `$.when.apply($, getBase64('#upload1', r.d)).then(...)`. I need to see the code to be able to help you more.

Comment: @Ljgazzano I updated my answer with the code you provided. You probably should have edited your question with the code instead of adding a new answer.